# Why doesn't the text follow the div it's inside?

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a website, and I came across a problem I don't understand at all. I have an  element inside a div. With text. At for some reason, the text expands and get de-positioned out of the box it is inside when I resize the browser.

**Here is a screenshot of how I want it to be. Even when I resize the browser:
https://gyazo.com/c972cdaf5cc3ed1fde14f49f7e7e9a7c**

**This is how it becomes when I resize the window:
https://gyazo.com/4ab18f515cca72c7490e8316c6ee9912**

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="bgBox1Main">
    <h1 class="bgBox1Title">RANK <br>BOOSTING</h1>
    <h1 class="bgBox1Click" onclick="goTo('rankboosting.php')">CLICK TO VIEW</h1>
    <div class="bgBox1" ></div>
    <p class="bgBox1Text">Get a proffessional booster to push you up to the ranks you want! Play with him or let him do the job alone.</p>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.bgBox1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 24vw;
    width: 17vw;
    background-color: #778beb;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px white;
}


.bgBox1Text{
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 12vw;
    width: 15vw;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
    max-height: 12vw;
    overflow: auto;
}

.bgBox1Title{
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 56%;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 25vw;
    width: 20vw;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
}
```

Comment: please include the CSS styles for `bgBox1Main` and `bgBox1Click` as well.

Answer (score 0):

add these rules to `.bgBox1Text`:

```
.bgBox1Text {
    text-align: justify;
    word-break: break-word; /* optionally */
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.bgBox1Main{
  position: relative;
  height: 24vw;
  width: 17vw;
  background-color:black;
}
.bgBox1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1vw;
    background-color: #778beb;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px white;
    text-align: center;
}

.bgBox1Title{
    font-size: 1.3vw;
}

.bgBox1Text{
    font-size: 1vw;
    flex-grow:1;
}


.bgBox1Click{
    font-size: 1.3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgBox1Main">
  <div class="bgBox1" >
      <h1 class="bgBox1Title">RANK <br>BOOSTING</h1>
      <p class="bgBox1Text">Get a proffessional booster to push you up to the ranks you want! Play with him or let him do the job alone.</p>
      <h1 class="bgBox1Click" onclick="goTo('rankboosting.php')">CLICK TO VIEW</h1>  
  </div>
</div>
```